# Transparent material turns black when unselected

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view, transparency

When I select eyebrows it looks good, the material is transparent. 
But when I deselect eyebrows it turns dark. 
Why? 
[image: object selected]

[image: object unselected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using an older version (2.78) of Blender and there are screenshots only this is a little bit of an guesswork.
Try the setup of the attached nodes. Instead of the "Principled BSDF" node use the Material node of Blender 2.78.
Additionally check the alpha channel settings of the viewport and the material.

[image]